# factory service doesn't save value correctly - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, factory

in my angular app i've created a factory service for store login information like name and surname. 
This factory store the info for know if the user is logged or not.
in $rootscope.on i need to check the isloggedin function, but always is undefined!

THE CODE:

**factory**

function auth($window)
  {
    var user;

```
return{
  setUser : function(nome, cognome, tipo){
    user.nome=nome;
    user.cognome=cognome;
    user.tipo=tipo;
  },
  isLoggedIn : function(){
    if(user.nome!==undefined){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  },
  utente : function(){
    return user;
  }
};
```

}
}());

**index.run**

```
if (!Auth.isLoggedIn) {
    console.log('DENY');
    event.preventDefault();
    $location.path('/login');
  }else{
    console.log('allow');
  }
```

Comment: Your `isLoggedIn` is function. Bu in code you don't fire the function. Try this `if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {...}`

Comment: i've try. but it's same! :(

Comment: For more detailed answer need example. Better jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because you are not storing the values, try to store the values in key value form in var , and check it when ever the authentication is required.
Like : var obj = {email:email,pwd:pwd}